# Is it possible to use Keras to classify images between one option or another?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To explain the title better, I am looking to classify pictures between two classes. For example, let's say that 0 is white, and black is 1. I train and validate the system with pictures that are gray, some lighter than others. In other words, none of the training/validation (t/v) pictures are 0, and none are 1. The t/v pictures range between 0 and 1 depending of how dark the gray is.

Of course, this is just a hypothetical situation, but I want to apply a similar scenario for my work. All of the information I have found online is based on a binary classification (either 1 or 0), rather than a spectrum classification (between 1 and 0).

I assume that this is possible, but I have no idea where to start. Although, I do have a binary code written with good accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your given example, maybe a classification approach is not the best one. I think that what you have is a regression problem, as you want your output to be a continuous value in some range, that has a meaning itself (as higher or lower values have a proper meaning).

Regression tasks usually have an output with linear activation, and they expect to have a continuous value as the ground truth.

I think you could start by taking a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) tutorial.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Carlos Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it's definitely possible.

The creator of *Keras*, François Chollet, wrote *Deep Learning with Python* which is worth reading. In it he describes how you could accomplish what you would like.

I have worked through examples in his book and shared the code: [whyboris/ml-with-python-and-keras](https://github.com/whyboris/ml-with-python-and-keras)

There are many approaches, but a fast one is to use a pre-trained model that can recognize a wide variety of images (for example, classify 1,000 different categories). You will use it "headless" (without the last classification layer that takes the vectors and decides which of the 1,000 categories it falls most into). And you will train just the "last step" in the model (freezing all the previous layers) while training your *binary* classifier.

Alternatively you could train your own classifier from scratch. Specifically glance at my example (based off the book) [cat-dog-classifier](https://github.com/whyboris/ml-with-python-and-keras/blob/master/cat-dog.py) which trains its own binary classifier.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will definitely look at the resources that you gave me. I am wondering though, what does the headless pre-trained model do, regarding a spectrum classification?

Comment: Sorry I was too hasty in reading your question. Your title asks for classifying images between two options, but your question seems to be about classifying things with a number on a continuum. Perhaps if the continuum is between two categories, you still do a binary classification, but since the model gives you a 'probability' output (not a binary 1 or 0) you can pretend it's a representation of a location on your spectrum.